# Solidity: get hash number from string;

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Is it possible somehow to get a uint256 hash from solidity array types such a strings or bytes32[]?

I want to create mapping (uint256 => address) where uint256 is a hash of some string what user entered earlier.
Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `keccak256()` on any Solidity type (including strings and arrays) to generate a `bytes32` hash. From there, you can either just use the `bytes32` result as your key or cast it to a `uint`.

[Solidity documentation on keccak](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions)